# CSS trouble on Virtualbox an MAMP?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, localhost, mamp, intranet

Today I found a really strange bug(?).
I'm running Mac OS X with MAMP and a Virtual box with Win XP.
In my hosts-file on the Mac OS I have added a line for localhost:8888, called "mampserver".
In the hosts-file on the XP I've set 10.0.2.2 (the Mac OS with MAMP) also to "mampserver". With these lines I can run WordPress locally on the MAMP and check it in IE from the virtual XP. 
(The reason why I have these host-strings is that WordPress saves GUIDs as `http://localhost:8888/the_site/...` and if I then on the XP tries to reach this directly from 10.0.2.2 images and other stuff will not be found because "localhost" is 127.0.0.1 on the XP).

Today however, I got a really strange bug using this set up.

If I from the MAMP runs something like:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-button">Button 1</div>
    <div class="menu-button">Button 2</div>
    <div class="menu-button">Button 3</div>
</div>
```

with the CSS looks something like:

```
#menu {
    width: 900px;
    display: table;
}
.menu-button {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

IE (8) renders this wrong, the `menu-button`:s is listed as rows. 
If i take the exact same code, creates a HTML-file on the XP and runs it in IE, it works perfect.

How can the host affect the CSS?!

Anyone who has been having the same or similar troubles?

Comment: I can't see any `<li>` elements here..

Comment: Probably has to do with your [Compatibility View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955410\(v=vs.85\).aspx) settings. In the case where it's being rendered wrong, it ends up being rendered in Quirks Mode. Check your settings, and use the Developer Tools (F12).

Comment: Sorry Mr.Alien. That's because i've tried them both and unfortunately i copied the wrong one here.
I'll fix it...

Comment: And yes Mercator, i just found out that it is default IE7 mode when i visit 10.0.2.2 and that was the problem. Any tip for forcing IE to use IE8 mode default?

Comment: If you're running in Compatibility Mode, usually means something is wrong with your DOCTYPE. Make sure you have a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration

Comment: @dgarbacz, i have 
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`. And it's the same in both files.

Comment: If you're using the strict doctype, you have to make sure your HTML is very sound. Try changing to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and see what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASPX page renders differently when reached on intranet vs. internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434020/aspx-page-renders-differently-when-reached-on-intranet-vs-internet)